# Get conic-gradient polyfill to work with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, polyfills

I'm trying to implement [this Polyfill](http://leaverou.github.io/conic-gradient/) in my Vue.js project:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script src="conic-gradient.js"></script>
```

I'm using a Vue instantiated with Vue-CLI with single file components and webpack.

The description seems so simple, include two script tags and bam it works.

I've added the conic-gradient NPM package to my project (`yarn add conic-gradient`) which fetches both the conic-gradient script as well as the required prefixfree.

I've then gone ahead trying a dry import in my main.js:

```js
import 'conic-gradient'
```

as well as

```js
import conic-gradient from 'conic-gradient'
```

and then calling:

```js
Vue.use(conic-gradient
```

I've also tried the dry import in my component (dome.vue)

Nothing seems to render the conic gradient however. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Conic-Gradient](http://leaverou.github.io/conic-gradient/) is not a Vue plugin, so you can't just do `Vue.use` with it.
Neither an ES6 module (sorry for late notice) so you can't use `import ConicGradient...`, the author published a failed npm package.

<s>Since you said your project was generated with Vue-CLI, then you must find the `src/main.js` file, and place your `import ConicGradient from 'conic-gradient'` at the top of it.</s>

And you can start using it like

```
import ConicGradient from 'conic-gradient'

new Vue({
    data: {
        gradient: new ConicGradient({
            stops: 'gold 40%, #f06 0',
            repeating: true,
            size: 400
       });
    }

})
```

Go to your `index.html` and paste this just before your body closing tag `</body>` (download that file and serve a local copy instead)

`<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/LeaVerou/conic-gradient/609dc5f4/conic-gradient.js"></script>`

Now in your Vue components you can use `new window.ConicGradient({ ... })`

### A working snippet

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = Vue.config.devtools = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    gradient: new window.ConicGradient({
      stops: 'red, yellow, lime, aqua, blue, magenta, red',
      size: 100
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/LeaVerou/conic-gradient/609dc5f4/conic-gradient.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16"></script>

<div id="app">
  <img :src="gradient.png" style="border-radius: 50%" />
</div>
```

Comment: So I need to do the import in the main.js as well as every component I use this in? I don't want to flood my main.js file with different gradients I'm using throughout the application.

Comment: You just import it in the components you need to use it. If you're not using it in the `main.js` file but another component, then don't import it in `main.js` file. Although you shall find yourself "importing" it in various components, webpack is in charge here and the code won't be "repeated". It's imported many times, **but loaded just once**. That's how ES6 modules work!

Comment: if I do: import ConicGradient from 'conic-gradient'

export default {
  name: 'dome',
  data () {
    return {
      gradient: new ConicGradient({
        stops: 'gold 40%, #f06 0'
      })
    }
  }
} I get an error that [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_conic_gradient___default.a is not a constructor"

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize that package wasn't es6 ready. It is published in the npm registry but you can't import it like an es6 module. I just edited my answer with another approach

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue in css, but it does work now in js, which is workable too

Comment: That happens because the elements are mounted after the library injects the "css polyfil" I believe. You also need to know you're using webpack in your cli-generated project. So you may better look up for a webpack solution for the css.